# File not uploading to the server

Tags: php, extjs, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using ExtJS and PHP.
My file is not uploading to the server.

JS:

```
function slidersave(){ 
    var form = sliderform.getForm();

    if (form.isValid()) {
        var slider_name=Ext.getCmp('txtslidername').getValue();
        var slider_image=Ext.getCmp('txtsliderimage').getValue();
        var slider_link=Ext.getCmp('txtsliderurl').getValue();
        form.submit({
            url: 'slider/file',
            waitMsg: 'Uploading your slider image...',
            success: function(form, o) {
                var obj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(o.response.responseText);
                alert(obj);
                if (obj.failed == '0' && obj.uploaded != '0') {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'All files uploaded');
                } else if (obj.uploaded == '0') {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Nothing Uploaded');
                } else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success',
                        obj.uploaded + ' files uploaded <br/>' +
                        obj.failed + ' files failed to upload');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
public function file()
{
    if(isset($_FILES)){
        $uploaddir = '/siteimages/slider/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['txtsliderimage']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtsliderimage']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            echo '{success: true}';
        } else {
            echo '{success: false}';
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting anything in the response the loader just disappears after sometime.

I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Did you tried to isolate the problem? "File is not uploaded" could be anything.

Comment: What does the request look like in the network tab of chrome developer tools?  Do you see the POST?  What's in the headers?